# Im trying to use beans in Spring for the purpose of a dependency injection but it says my tags have no body

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am using the Spring framework and when I am trying to use beans for dependency injections I am getting the error "xml tags have no body".
This is the code for my App.java class.

```
 package com.spring;
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    vehicle obj = (vehicle)context.getBean("vehicle");
    obj.drive();

}
}
```

And this is the code in my xml file;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="vehicle" class="com.spring.Car"></bean>
</beans>
```

this is the error it produces when ran;

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=53412:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Mello\IdeaProjects\scrabble\target\classes;C:\Users\Mello.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Mello.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Mello.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Mello.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Mello.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Mello.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar" com.spring.App
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:177)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at com.spring.App.main(App.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1

edited code;

```
package com.spring;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    vehicle obj = (vehicle)context.getBean("vehicle");
    obj.drive();

}
```

}

[final issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB5Nx.png)

Comment: The error you're getting is "BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext". Have you tried doing what the error message tells you to do? Why don't you pass the location of the xml file to the constructor of the context?

Comment: @JBNizet I have tried this but it says that the file cannot be found, see updated code in my latest edit. Regards, Jake.

Comment: How do you build your project? Is it a Maven or Gradle project? Where is the spring.xml file located in your project?

Comment: Its built using maven, I hope i don't get shot for this but a screenshot is in the edit... ive named it file structure.

Comment: Resources go under src/main/resources, not under src/main/java. And it must not be in the package com.spring, since the path you pass is `spring.xml`, and not `com/spring/spring.xml`

Comment: I've tried moving things around and put the xml file in a file called Resources and still no luck after referencing here. Ive put another screenshot at the end of the post.

Comment: **Read** my comment. The file must be named spring.xml, and must be located under `src/main/resources`, not under `src/main/java/com/spring`. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I will read through that now. I have created a file called resources under src/main/resources. I have put another picture on with this showing.

Comment: I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: I have marked the resources file as the resources root and got the file to run, there are no exceptions produced but I am still getting the warning stating that the xml tag has no body. It worked as it should though.

Comment: The xml warning is just tellin you that you could simplify the markup by using `<bean id="vehicle" class="com.spring.Car" />`

Comment: Ow right, thank you for your help and patience as I'm new to Maven. Thanks, Jake.